# Angular 8/Ionic 5: "values is null" on POST request

Tags: post, angular8, angular-httpclient, ionic5

Since yesterday, I'm stuck with an issue and I don't find anything to help me T.T

I'm working on an Angular 8 with Ionic 5 app for Android. I just want to make a POST request to an API. Yep, that's all ^^

I have a *register.page.html* with a register form, then on submit it calls the **submitForm()** function in *register.page.ts*.
This function calls the **registerUser()** function in *user.service.ts*. This is where I make the POST request to my API.

But everything goes wrong, and all I got is an error `values is null` in my console. The request is never send, and when I `console.log` my variables, everything seems fine.

Here are the files.

**register.page.html:**

```html
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>Créer un compte</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <form (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
        <ion-item lines="full">
            <ion-label position="floating">Nom d'utilisateur</ion-label>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="user.username" name="username" type="text" required></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item lines="full">
            <ion-label position="floating">Email</ion-label>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="user.email" name="email" type="email" required></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item lines="full">
            <ion-label position="floating">Mot de passe</ion-label>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="password" type="password" required></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                <ion-button type="submit" color="danger" expand="block">Créer un compte</ion-button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

**register.page.ts:**

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from '../services/user.service';
import {User} from '../classes/user';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-register',
    templateUrl: './register.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./register.page.scss'],
})
export class RegisterPage implements OnInit {

    user: User;

    constructor(
        private userService: UserService,
    ) {
        this.user = new User();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    submitForm(): void {
        this.userService.registerUser(this.user)
            .subscribe(res => {
                console.log(res);
            }, err => {
                console.error(err);
            });
    }

}
```

**user.service.ts:**

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {User} from '../classes/user';
import {ApiService} from './api.service';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {catchError, retry} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

    currentUser: User;

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private apiService: ApiService
    ) {
    }

    registerUser(user: User): Observable<any> {
        return this.http
            .post<any>(this.apiService.apiUrl + '/users', user, this.apiService.httpOptions)
            .pipe(
                retry(3),
                catchError(this.apiService.handleError)
            );
    }
}
```

**api.service.ts:**

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

    apiUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1';
    httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Accept: 'application/json',
            Authorization: null,
        })
    };
    token = null;

    constructor() {
    }

    handleError(error): Observable<never> {
        let errorMessage = '';

        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
            errorMessage = error.error.message;
        } else {
            errorMessage = 'Error code: ' + error.status + '\nMessage: ' + error.message;
        }

        return throwError(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts:**

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {RouteReuseStrategy} from '@angular/router';

import {IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy} from '@ionic/angular';
import {SplashScreen} from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import {StatusBar} from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';

import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    entryComponents: [],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        {
            provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
            useClass: IonicRouteStrategy,
        },
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't works... If you have any idea, I really appreciate your help!
Thanks!

Comment: Declare an object of type User and asaign the ngmodel values to this object and at last insert the object instead of class in register.

Comment: @MostafaHarb I'm not sure I understand. I removed `this.user = new User();` in constructor of _register.page.ts_, and replaced `user: User;` by `user: User = new User();` in the same file. But it doesn't change anything. I tried to put directly the object (without attributes) in my `[(ngModel)]`, but got **[object Object]** in my fields. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No i mean declare object postdata = {username:'',email:'',...} and in ngModel call postdata.username an so on on others. And send the postdata in ur api request, if it works then later we do a small change and we change the userdata to type User nut first test on it.

Comment: @MostafaHarb Oh ok! I did it, but still not better :( I replaced `user: User;` with `user = {username: '', email: '', password: ''};` and `registerUser(user: User)` with `registerUser(user: any)` in _user.service.ts_, but the same error append...

Comment: Easity console.log(user in ngsubmit XD) and see if it have values, if it have values then the problem from other than this page else tell me the lig value :(

Comment: @MostafaHarb There is values: `Object { username: "jhgf", email: "jhfg", password: "jhgf" }`, this is why I don't understand where the problem occurs... I already did POST call on another Angular app, everything runs fine. For this case, my first Ionic project, I followed tons of guides, but nothing works. I probably have something misconfigured, but I can't find where. My project if new, I just start with these files. I'm lost ahah! Thanks again for your time ;)

Comment: Ah and in your post service remove registeruser(user:User and change it to user) without declaring its type.

Comment: I tried with `(user: any)`and just `(user)` but nothing works T.T

Comment: Try to subscribe to post in register ^_*

Comment: I already tried in **submitForm()** and in **registerUser()** (after the .pipe() and without the .pipe()), with the same result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it!

In *api.service.ts*, one header was initialized with a null value like this:

```js
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: null, // The bad guy.
    })
};
```

I have to change it with an empty value:

```js
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: '', // The good guy.
    })
};
```